# Getting index of duplicate letters in a string

Tags: string, python-3.x, indexing, zelle-graphics

```
from graphics import *
import random 

def hangman(word):
    returnStuff = {'again':0, '1st':1}

    alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
                'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

    win = GraphWin("Hangman", 800, 550)
    win.setBackground("yellow")

    titleText = Text(Point(400,50), 'HANGMAN')
    titleText.setSize(24)
    titleText.setStyle('bold')
    titleText.draw(win)

    #Building the hangman base
    base = Line(Point(120,350),Point(230,350))
    base.draw(win)
    stand = Line(Point(175,350),Point(175,150))
    stand.draw(win)
    stand2 = Line(Point(175,150),Point(250,150))
    stand2.draw(win)
    stand3 = Line(Point(250,150),Point(250,180))
    stand3.draw(win)

    #drawing the empty lines for the word
    x1 = 150
    x2 = 180
    l = 0
    print(word)
    while l< len(word):
        wordLine = Line(Point(x1, 420),Point(x2,420))
        wordLine.draw(win)
        l+=1
        x1+=40
        x2+=40

    guessCounter = 0
    textCheck = 0
    invalidText = Text(Point(600,100), 'You did not enter a valid letter.')
    invalidText.setTextColor('red')
    indexes = []
    while guessCounter < 6:
        #text entry box
        textEntry = Entry(Point(600,180),10)
        textEntry.draw(win)
        guessText = Text(Point(600,150), 'Guess a letter:')
        guessText.draw(win)
        #user has to click this box to confirm the letter
        enterBox = Rectangle(Point(580,200), Point(620,220))
        enterBox.setFill('white')
        enterBox.draw(win)
        clickText = Text(Point(600,210), 'Enter')
        clickText.draw(win)

        click = win.getMouse()
        x = click.getX()
        y = click.getY()

        if 580 < x < 620 and 200 < y < 220:
            guess = textEntry.getText().lower().strip()
            if guess not in alphabet:
                if textCheck == 0:
                    invalidText.draw(win)
                    textCheck = 1

            else:
                if textCheck == 1:
                    invalidText.undraw()
                    textCheck = 0
                for letter in word:
                    if letter == guess:
                        indexes.append(word.index(guess))
                        print(indexes)


    win.getMouse()

    win.close()

    return returnStuff 

#list with various words pertaining to nanotechnology
words = ['nanotechnology', 'science', 'nanometre' , 'strength', 'chemistry',
         'small', 'molecule', 'light' , 'weight', 'technology', 'materials',
         'property', 'physics', 'engineering', 'matter', 'waterloo', 'nanobot',
         'reaction', 'structure', 'cells']

#picks a random word from the list
word = random.choice(words)

#this variable ensures it opens the game the first time
initialCall = 1
#stores the returnValue for the first call
returnValue = hangman(word)

#sets the initialCall to 0 after first call 
if returnValue['1st']==1:
    initialCall=0

#Calls the game function again if user wishes
while initialCall == 1 or returnStuff['again'] == 1:
    returnValue = hangman(word)
```

I am making Hangman in Python graphics. I apologize for the huge block of code, it all works fine, I just thought it must be useful. The part of the code that I'm concerned about is this:

```
            else:
                if textCheck == 1:
                    invalidText.undraw()
                    textCheck = 0
                for letter in word:
                    if letter == guess:
                        indexes.append(word.index(guess))
                        print(indexes)
```

This block of code will be executed when the user's letter guess is in the alphabet, I then run through each letter in the chosen word, and if at any point a letter in the word is the same as the guess letter, I store the index of that letter in a empty list so I can use that to tell the computer where to draw the letters on the empty lines.

It works fine, with the exception of when there is a duplicate letter in the word. For example, engineering has 3 es. Unfortunately, .index() only records the index for when the letter appears the first time, and it disregards the other letters. **What is the work around for this so I can get the indexes of all 3 es in that word, instead of 3 indexes of just the first e.** For testing purposes, I have printed the chosen word and the index list on the console so I can see what's going on and so I don't actually have to guess a letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
def indexes(word,letter):
    for i,x in enumerate(word):
        if x == letter:
            yield i
```

test

```
>>> list( indexes("engineering","e") )
[0, 5, 6]
>>>
```

this function is a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generato), that is a lazy function that only give result when asked for then, to get a individual result you use `next`, the functions is execute until the first [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) then return the result and stop its execution and remember where it was, until another call to next is executed in witch point resume execution from the previous point until the next yield, if the is no more raise StopIteration, for example:

```
>>> word="engineering"
>>> index_e = indexes(word,"e")
>>> next(index_e)
0
>>> print(word)
engineering
>>> next(index_e)
5
>>> next(index_e)
6
>>> next(index_e)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    next(index_e)
StopIteration
>>>
```

to update a list with the result of this function, you can use the extend method

```
>>> my_list=list()
>>> index_e = indexes(word,"e")
>>> my_list.extend( index_e )
>>> my_list
[0, 5, 6]
>>>
```

generator are used in cases where their result is only a intermediary step to something else because they use a minimum amount of memory, but in this case maybe you want the whole thing so use it as the first example or remake the function to return a list in the first place like this

```
def indexes(word,letter):
    result = list()
    for i,x in enumerate(word):
        if x == letter:
            result.append(i)
    return result
```

sorry if I confuse you with the yield thing.

Comment: how exactly did you implement this? Do i call the indexes function within the for letter in word for loop? What exactly does yield i do?

Comment: the `yield` make this function a generator, that is a lazy function that give result when asked for it, you can think of it as a virtual list that give its elements as you iterate over it

Comment: yo yield i is basically returning the index of the letter each time its found? And i just say indexes.append(i)?

Comment: also check: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions

Comment: I cant seem to get it to work, I called the function and stored i in the indexes list and it says this when i print indexes: [<generator object indexFind at 0x00C140D0>]

Comment: I update it, I have not check your whole code yet but some of the examples may help you